# Magento2: Cart with discount code higher then the amount in cart shows -€ NaN,N as grand total

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart

We added 1 product to cart with the price of 10.99
Tax applied is 5.99
when applied a discount code of 50 euro
the grand total incl tax = € NaN,N

Can anyone suggest what could be the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've fixed this issue by overriding below js file in theme and updated getValue() function in it:
Magento_Tax/web/js/view/checkout/summary/grand-total.js

Before:

```
getValue: function() {
                var price = 0;
                if (this.totals()) {
                    price = totals.getSegment('grand_total').value;
                }
                return this.getFormattedPrice(price);
            },
```

After:

```
getValue: function() {
                var price = 0;
                if (this.totals()) {
                    price = parseFloat(totals.getSegment('grand_total').value).toFixed(2);
                }
                return this.getFormattedPrice(price);
            },
```

parseFloat just added to make sure it should return float value.
Hope this helps someone.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This issue is already reported in GitHub https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/18027

The issue got fixed in version 2.2.8

Comment: Not quite the same issue - the described issue is still present in 2.3.1 which includes the fix for issue 18027